# Don't support turkish character with export pdfmake

Tags: jspdf, bootstrap-table, pdfmake, data-export

I am using Bootstrap table. When I click data-export button and I select PDF, content doesn't support Turkish character.
Document is up.

[image]

Comment: What kind of export-tool do you use? Have you declared your encodings the right way? Does the PDF-Export tool support turkish encodings?
First cheack this pleas and give more informations then we will see.
You maybe can switch to unicode so everything will be supported (is framework/tool does)

Comment: I am using exportTypes: 'pdf', I added <script type="text/javascript" src="colResizable/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="colResizable/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="colResizable/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="colResizable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>   but dont support turkish character

Comment: The normal way does use `UTF-8` - you need to use an other encoding for turkish language. For example `unicode` for supporting all - but I guess by default this is just working for UTF-8.

Comment: I know error is utf-8 but I dont find utf-8 support

Comment: You mean you don´t find `unicode`-Support? There is no real support - it´s a `UTF-8` feature and default

Comment: Thank you. I used dataTable. Problem solved